# How to Skip Columns of CSV file

Tags: python, csv, google-api, google-bigquery, google-python-api

I am trying to upload data from certain fields in a CSV file to an already existing table.

From my understanding, the way to do this is to create a new table and then append the relevant columns of the newly created table to the corresponding columns of the main table.

How exactly do I append certain columns of data from one table to another?
As in, what specific commands?

I am using the bigquery api and the python-client-library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas library for that.

`import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv('input_data.csv')
useful_columns = [col1, col2, ... ] # List the columns you need data[useful_columns].to_csv('result_data.csv', index=False) # index=False is to prevent creating extra column`

Comment: This works, except that each field in the new CSV file contains the value of the field to the right of it in the original file. Any built in argument that addresses this?

Comment: yes there is! I passed in `index_col=False` to the function `read_csv()` and that did the trick